# Converting "literal" unicode character to an equivalent without emphasising

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode-string

I have as an input one string containing "literal" unicode characters.

```
"I want to replace \u00c6 with AE and \u00d5 with O"
```

note :
\u00c6 = Æ
\u00d5 = Ö

So with my python script, I can easyly replace one character :

```
>>> print("I want to replace \u00c6 with AE and \u00d5 with O".replace(u"\u00c6","AE"))
I want to replace AE with AE and Õ with O
```

But what if I want to replace them all ? (there is only 2 in the example, but we can imagine we have to search for 50 charaters to be replaced.

I tried to use a dict to do the matching, but this does not seem to work

```
#input  : "\u00c0 \u00c1 \u00c2 \u00d2 \u00c4 \u00c5 \u00c6 \u00d6"
#output (expected) : "A A A O A A AE 0"

import sys

unicode_table = {
   '\u00c0': 'A',  #À
   '\u00c1': 'A',  #Á
   '\u00c2': 'A',  #Â
   '\u00c3': 'A',  #Ã
   '\u00c4': 'A',  #Ä
   '\u00c5': 'A',  #Å
   '\u00c6': 'AE', #Æ
   '\u00d2': 'O',  #Ò
   '\u00d3': 'O',  #Ó
   '\u00d4': 'O',  #Ô
   '\u00d5': 'O',  #Õ
   '\u00d6': 'O'   #Ö
   #this may go on much further
}

result = sys.argv[1]

for key in unicode_table:
   #print(key + unicode_table[key])
   result = result.replace(key,unicode_table[key])

print(result)
```

output :

```
[puppet@damageinc python]$ python replace_unicode.py "\u00c0 \u00c1 \u00c2 \u00d2 \u00c4 \u00c5 \u00c6 \u00d6"
\u00c0 \u00c1 \u00c2 \u00d2 \u00c4 \u00c5 \u00c6 \u00d6
```

Any help appreciated !
Thanks.

edit : Two solutions with the comments, thanks

1st : reencode the string with unicode_escape :

```
result = sys.argv[1].encode().decode('unicode_escape')
```

2nd : use module unidecode, just to avoid rediscovering the wheel

```
import sys
from unidecode import unidecode

result = sys.argv[1].encode().decode('unicode_escape')
print(unidecode(result))
```

Comment: Take a look at [unidecode](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/).

Comment: Your Python code works as expected, it's your shell that doesn't render the escape sequences. You should try testing it with some actual unicode strings. Or maybe add `echo` with `-e` to your command: `python replace_unicode.py "$(echo -e '\u00c0 ... \u00d6')"`.

Comment: `print("I want to replace \u00c6 with AE and \u00d5 with O")` correctly displays `I want to replace Æ with AE and Õ with O`.

Comment: Thanks Czaporka, you're absolutely right. result = sys.argv[1].encode().decode('unicode_escape') has perfectly done the trick

Comment: @Czaporka can you post your comment as an answer ? thx

Comment: If you do `unicode_trans = str.maketrans(unicode_table)` you can then replace your for loop with `result = result.translate(unicode_trans)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Python code works as expected, it's your shell that doesn't render the escape sequences, i.e. the Python script receives literally "\u00c0" instead of "À", etc.

You should try testing it with some actual unicode strings, or maybe tweak your command by adding e.g. `printf` or `echo -e` to render the escape sequences before passing them to the script:

```sh
python replace_unicode.py "$(printf '\u00c0 ... \u00d6')"
```